# How can I determine Internal IP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a web service on IIS and I have two network interface cards. In my service I have code:

```
string host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

    IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[2];
```

It gives me external ip adress, how I can find internal ip?

Comment: What is in AddressList[0] and AddressList[1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the local ip address(es) by calling `Dns.GetHosEntry("")`. That is, passing an empty string as the host name.

Alternatively you can use the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` method and go from there.